# Query not retrieving today's records

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to get all the records I have in my table that is from today, but
for some reason it doesn't want to happen. I get an empty collection

Here is my code

```
    $products = Product::where('created_at', Carbon::today())->get();
    dd($products);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because it's trying to make an exact match (date **and time**) and given that `today()` returns a datetime of the beginning of the day it will only capture records with that exact `created_at` value.

What you could do to mitigate this, is to check for values more recent than that timestamp:

```
$products = Product::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today())
                 ->get();
```

A nicer way to accomplish it is to make use of the `whereDate` method which only takes in account the date:

```
$products = Product::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())
                 ->get();
```

Check more alternatives in [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-clauses).

Answer (score 0):

you should take all the records with created from the very begin of today and so on.

```
  $products = Product::where('created_at','>=', Carbon::today()->startOfDay())->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

**use the following way :**

```
$products = Product::whereRaw('date(created_at) = date(now())')->get();
```